# Difference between typescript module "None" and "CommonJS"

Tags: typescript

It seems that using tsc with `compilerOptions.module` set to `None` or `CommonJS` is producing the same transpiled code. How do these two differ? Why are there two options for producing (apparently) the same transpiled code?

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `module` set to `None`, we *cannot* use imports, exports, or module augmentations (except for the way that @artem notes in the below comments.)

Here is [the source of the message](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/2b1078441570ac2ad18788d39422cdfdabeb2835/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json#L450-L453).

```
"Cannot use imports, exports, or module augmentations when '--module' is 'none'.": {
    "category": "Error",
    "code": 1148
},
```

With `module` set to `CommonJS`, if we *choose* not to use imports, exports, or module augmentations, then our output might look the same as it does when we set `module` to `None`.

Comment: How strict is the statement "*cannot* use imports"? because I did not know this, and I used them anyway, the compiler did not error out, and the result was identical to setting `module` to `CommonJS`

Comment: @aryzing Good point. I tested just now. The ban on `export` seems strict whereas the use of `import` seems allowed.

Comment: It's actually "can't have any imports or exports at the top level". Imports and exports inside namespaces are fine because they don't export anything from `.ts` file at runtime, and as long as file remains 'not a module' `module=None` works  fine. Long explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38666021/43848

Comment: @artem In a test using TypeScript 2.4.1, an import inside a namespace gave the error: "Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module." Inside `foo.ts` was `namespace test { import "./bar"; }` and inside `bar.ts` was `namespace test { export const x = 10; }`. The error occurred in `foo.ts` even when the `bar.ts` was empty. Can you provide an example of a working import inside a namespace when module is set to none?

Comment: with `module=none` you can use only import assignment for creating [aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases), you can't import from modules. Example: file `a.ts`: `namespace A { import b = B.b; console.log(b); ` file `b.ts`: `namespace B { export var b = 'b' }` compile with `tsc --module none --outFile o.js b.ts a.ts` . This part of language predates ES modules and is now mostly of historical interest. Also, when doing this, you are supposed to use `reference` directives to ensure proper initialization order at runtime.

Comment: @artem Perfect. That's what I needed.