# Make a exported class visible globally

Tags: typescript

I've defined a class inside a module and exported it as default, like this:

```
// file: Component.ts
import UIComponent  from "path/to/UIComponent";

namespace typescript.example.app
{
    export class Component extends UIComponent
    {
        ...
    }
}

export default typescript.example.app.Component;
```

In another file, unless I want to use the Component class at runtime (create an instance or call a static method), I don't need to import it.

```
// file: UseComponent.ts
namespace typescript.example.app
{
    export class UseComponent
    {
        ...
        // error: namespace typescript.example.app has no exported member Component
        public myMethod(component: typescript.example.app.Component) { ... }
        ...
    }
}

export default typescript.example.app.UseComponent;
```

How can I make `typescript.example.app.Component` globally visible with it being declared inside a module?

Comment: Export the `namespace`.

Comment: Tried to put `export namespace typescript;` before the `export default typescript.example.app.Component;` and got this error: "Individual declarations in merged declaration 'typescript' must be all exported or all local."

Comment: I'm working with a framework and I need to export the class as default

Comment: Do not use any "namespaces". Just use ES6 modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Namespaces* are a non-standard feature that TypeScript keeps in order to mislead beginners. Use ES6 modules only:

```
// file: Component.ts
import UIComponent  from "path/to/UIComponent";

export default class Component extends UIComponent {
  // ...
}
```

And then:

```
// file: UseComponent.ts
import Component from "./Component";

export default class UseComponent {
  public myMethod(component: Component) {
  }
}
```

See also:

- The [introduction to ES6 modules from Mozilla](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/);
- [How to use namespaces with import in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37565709/3786294);
- [Modules vs. Namespaces: What is the correct way to organize a large typescript project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39827281/3786294);
- [Module vs Namespace - Import vs Require Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38582352/3786294).

Comment: This is exactly what I don't wanna do. Why import a module if I won't need it  after compilation? Its only use is in a argument's type, after typescript transpile it into javascript, it won't exist in my code anymore...

Comment: @lmcarreiro TypeScript doesn't generate the `import` if it is not needed in JavaScript. You can try.

Comment: I'm convinced, if this is the right way, let's do it. Thanks.