# Using namespaces to avoid importing from each file

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript-namespace

According to this article, you can use TypeScript namespaces to import types/interfaces without including an import:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-useful-typescript-tips-for-angular

However if I create a namepsace:

```
export namespace ST {

  export interface Ifoo {

  }
}
```

in order to get it recognized, I have to import it like so:

```
import {ST} from 'suman-types/dts/foo';

export const foo : ST.Ifoo = function () {

};
```

is there something I am doing wrong? How can I use a namespace to easily import code?

Perhaps this only works with Angular and doesn't really work with CommonJS/Node.js? Not sure why not though.

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned on the page you refer to this is actually not bound to Angular only.

What I can see on the fist glance is that you use `export` with the namespace itself.

```
export namespace ST {
      export interface Ifoo { }
}
```

The example on scotch.io says you‘re supposed to use export only with the nested interfaces. Like this:

```
namespace ST {
      export interface Ifoo { }
}
```

This should do the trick. Then no further `import` should be needed. You‘re supposed to be able to use the namespace throughout the app without any further input statement.

Comment: I wonder if this works if the namespace is included in node_modules instead of in the "include" property of your tsconfig

Comment: I have typeRoots set like this, so maybe that will work: ` "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/suman-types/dts"
    ],`

Comment: Maybe this link gives you the needed hint as tutorial often presuppose knowledge you don‘t have and leave out important information: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Comment: Another useful post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582352/module-vs-namespace-import-vs-require-typescript